Track res.user activity live on specific model with Odoo
I would like to know if it's possible to track if a user is logged on a ticket form in Odoo, like Zendesk does ? Zendesk displays when someone on your team is currently working on a ticket so that prevents to work on something that one of his coworker is actually working on.
But would this feature be possible with Odoo ? If it's possible how ?
Thanks a lot
